# Are OS drivers needed for True Hardware RAID?

Tags: raid, hardware-raid

Do you need to install drivers for a True Hardware Raid controller? What are the indicators of a True Hardware RAID Controller?

Comment: "true hardware raid" is technically a software raid running on a slower cpu than you have on motherboard. If you using linux then mdraid is always the recommended.

Comment: @lpor-Sircer isnt hardware raid independent of the OS? Like the OS will be presented with a logical disk and it will think this disk is like any other disk.?

Comment: @Ipor Sircer   if that cpu is a dedicated RAID controller then it is a hardware raid  not a software RAID